# AWK - pass array of strings as a variable in order to print columns from TSV file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, command-line, printing

I've stored column number as array of strings in a separate variable and I would like to provide that variable as an input in AWK print.

So, I want to create a variable storing $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 and to pass that as input.

The first part, creating a variable, I have succeeded with this piece of code:

```
clm=$(
     awk -F"\t" '{print NF}' broj.tsv |
     sort -nu |               
     tail -n 1) && 
     comma_arr=$(seq -s, 1 $clm | 
     sed 's/^/\$/; s/,$//; s/,/,$/g')
```

After running `&& echo "$comma_arr"` I can see the desired output which is **$1,$2,$3,$4,$5**.

Next step would be to pass the comma_arr as an input in AWK print.

What I've tried is:

```
&& awk -v c=$comma_arr '{print c}' broj.tsv
```

but that gives me back that same array of strings as output: **$1,$2,$3,$4,$5**.

I am searching for the simplest way to do this but I have no success. Please if you can explain me how this can be achieved and what is wrong here (I do understand that by passing only "c" awk recognises this as a string to be printed instead of column order).

Comment: Are you expecting it to recursively evaluate each `$1`, `$2`, etc. as an expression and print its value? Why would it do that? It just prints the string literally.

Comment: instead of trying to 'fix' the  current (somewhat convoluted) code, perhaps you could provide a) a sample set of input, b) an explanation of what you wish to do with that sample intput and c) the expected result

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. Are you asking me why do I want to do this? If that's the question, because I need it for something bigger that I want to do, later on I would change this string based on certain parameter and then pass it as input while spliting the characters by comma. However, this is the basic knowledge that I need in order to understand how to do something more complex. I understand that I can print columns with AWK in an easier way, but I need to do it like this. @Barmar

Comment: I think that the question is pretty understandable. I know that after explaining what I want to do people will write me to simply use AWK without the variable passing, because what I want to do is to print first five columns from the TSV file. However, I want to learn how to pass a variable containing array of strings on this example because I know other ways to print a columns. @markp-fuso

Comment: it looke like `broj.tsv` has 5 fields, you generate the series `$1,$2,$3,$4,$5`, and then you want to pass this series to `awk` to .... print all 5 fields in `broj.tsv` ... ???  so you want to print all fields in `broj.tsv`, right? the only thing I can possibly see is that `broj.tsv` might have a variable number of fields so you want to find the max number of fields and then ... convert all input lines to contain the same (max) number of fields ... ??

Answer (score 2):

Just put the column numbers in the variable, without `$` before them. Split it up and iterate over that to get what you want.

```
comma_arr=1,2,3,4,5
awk -v "c=$comma_arr" '
    BEGIN {split(c, cols, ",")} 
    {for (i in cols) printf("%s ", $cols[i]); 
     print ""
}'
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you @Barmar. I am learning here, so please correct me if I misunderstood something:
first -v part is simple variable setting, BEGIN part splits the c variable into elements separated by commas, {for (i in cols) printf("%s ", $cols[i]); print ""} iterates over each row of the input file and prints the values of the columns specified in c?

Comment: Right. `cols[i]` is an element of the array, and `$cols[i]` is the column named by that element.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data set:

```
$ cat sample.dat
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
a b c d e f g
```

One `awk` approach for designating the list of columns to print:

```
for list in '1,2,3,4' '4,1,6,2,3' '1,1,1,1'
do
    echo "######## list = $list"

    awk -v list="${list}" '
    BEGIN { n=split(list,cols,",") }
          { for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
                printf "%s%s", (i==1 ? "" : OFS), $(cols[i])
            print ""
          }
    ' sample.dat
done
```

This generates:

```
######## list = 1,2,3,4
1 2 3 4
a b c d
######## list = 4,1,6,2,3
4 1 6 2 3
d a f b c
######## list = 1,1,1,1
1 1 1 1
a a a a
```